# Android tesseract data path

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract

So I'm following tutorials and below is my code. I'm stuck trying to figure out what I need to with the data path.  Does anyone have an example or suggestion on how to take the bitmap photo I took and get it loaded into tesseract to analyze?  All help appreciated.

```
package com.example.cameraocr;

import java.io.File;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    private static ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new     Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
} 
protected static void identifyunicode() {
    // DATA_PATH = Path to the storage
    // lang for which the language data exists, usually "eng"

    File myDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED); 
    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI(); 
    baseApi.init(myDir, "eng");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at my example:

https://github.com/akiwarheit/plug-notes-android/blob/master/src/com/plug/note/NoteEditorActivity.java

What I did was call the camera, take a photo, get the photo and pass it to my `OCRTask` class (an AsyncTask) which calls the `TessBaseAPI`

```
  public void callCamera() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting camera...");
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_OCR);
  }
```

https://github.com/akiwarheit/plug-notes-android/blob/master/src/com/plug/note/OCRTask.java

(A bit long if I post the entire `OCRTask` class code here, so just read it in Github, maybe?)

And handled the result afterwards

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    /* bunch of other codes */
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_OCR) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap x = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");            
        new OCRTask(this, x, this).execute();            
      }
    }
  }
```

I just added the text it recognized to my `EditText`

```
  @Override
  public void onFinishRecognition(String recognizedText) {
    noteView.setText(noteView.getText() + " " + recognizedText);
  }
```

---

*Here are the classes*

[NoteEditor (calls the Camera intent)](https://github.com/akiwarheit/plug-notes-android/blob/master/src/com/plug/note/NoteEditorActivity.java)

[OCRTask (calls the `TessBaseApi`, this is your main concern)](https://github.com/akiwarheit/plug-notes-android/blob/master/src/com/plug/note/OCRTask.java)

[OCRCallback (Adds the text to my `EditText` after `OCRTask` finishes)](https://github.com/akiwarheit/plug-notes-android/blob/master/src/com/plug/note/OCRCallback.java)

[FileManager (util method)](https://github.com/akiwarheit/plug-notes-android/blob/master/src/com/plug/utils/FileManager.java)

Hope it helps.